# Typescript getSelection disappear

Tags: javascript, typescript, getselection

In Vue and typescript I have my own context menu:

```
<context-menu id="context-menu" ref="ctxMenu">
      <li @click="ctxMenuClickItem1($event)" v-on:mouseover="menuItemMouseover($event)" v-on:mouseleave="menuItemMouseleave($event)" v-bind:style="getMenuItemStyle()" >Open in TMS</li>
      <li @click="ctxMenuClickItem2($event)" v-on:mouseover="menuItemMouseover($event)" v-on:mouseleave="menuItemMouseleave($event)" v-bind:style="getMenuItemStyle()" >Open in OnDemand</li>
      <li @click="doCopy()" >Copy</li>
    </context-menu>
```

And when I selected text on the page and then I click third item in context menu (doCopy) the selection disappear.

Do copy function looks like this:

```
 doCopy: function () {
  debugger;
  var selection = window.getSelection();
},
```

and after click selection is empty: selection.toString() is ""

How to copy selected text?

Comment: get state of selection in copy function, if selection.isCollapsed === true , you can't copy text.

Comment: And ,please, give code  of funcion 'doCopy'

Comment: I've added whole doCopy function
Ok, but how to set isCollapsed to false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click in the context menu, your selection is  collapsing (or reset) maybe because  moving focus. You need to get a selection when the event  'contextmenu' triggered, and restore selection in doCopy.
Example for JS:

```
var range = document.createRange();
docucment.addEventListener('contextmenu', (ev) => {
    let selection = window.getSelection();
    if(selection.rangeCount > 0) {}
    range = selection.getRangeAt(0);
})
doCopy = function(){
  let selection = window.getSelection();
  selection.removeAllRanges();
  selection.addRange(range);
  document.execCommand('copy');//save selection in buffer

}
```

If you select text in contenteditable element, you need set focus in that element.

Comment: context menu I have from this website: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-context-menu 
<div @contextmenu.prevent="$refs.ctxMenu.open">
  ...
</div>
But how to connect to this event to add your code?